# How disable to print stack trace in angular $http method call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stack-trace

In my test application I call a function to see the current logged user. This may end up with "401 (Unauthorized)", which is normal behaviour in this case. But angular prints an error stack into log:

**js code**

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:9000/currentUser'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.currentUser = data.user
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.currentUser = "Anonymous"
    });
```

**stack trace**

```
GET http://localhost:9000/rest/user 401 (Unauthorized)
  $get.id   angular.min.js:96
  ...
```

How can I disable printing the stack trace in this method call?